# Supertest with Knex

Tags: postgresql, express, chai, knex.js, supertest

So, I'm currently writing my supertest suite for my Express/PostgreSQL app. But I have to write tests that involve knex. I need to specify a "test" database for it to connect to instead. This way it can post, truncate, etc. all it needs to without affecting the main database. How do I tell supertest/chai to use a different knex connection than what my app.js specifies?

I do have a "setup" file that my "npm test" script requires chai to use. But it only has the require node modules and just a couple of variable declarations to make writing the test suite easier. Should something go in there to specify the knex connection?

I'm sure I could add extra .env variables and call on them to avoid hardcoding the login info to the test database.

I also have an SQL script I know I would need to run each time on the test database to start fresh. Knex can handle that I know.

Comment: How are you creating the connection in your app?

Comment: With knex. I load the connection info (postgres url) from a .env variable.